# mysql "Incorrect integer value"

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mariadb, mysql-connector

I am trying to insert values into my database, and automatically filling the foreign key value in one of my databases. But I receive this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1366 (22007): Incorrect integer value: 'CAST(SELECT ID FROM article WHERE title = UDASSA) as INT' for column 'knowledgebase'.'article_fulltext'.'article_ID' at row 1
```

Python3 code:

article:

```Python
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="...", password="...", database="knowledgebase")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO article (title, author, summary, source) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
val = (article.title.strip(), ", ".join(article.authors), summary.strip(), url.strip())

mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()

sql = "INSERT INTO article_fulltext (article_ID, body_text, html) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
foreign_key = "CAST(SELECT ID FROM article WHERE title = " + article.title + ") as INT"
val = ( foreign_key, article.text.strip(), article.html.strip() )

mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

`ID` in table `article` is INT (auto_increment) and my foreign key `article_ID` in table `article_fulltext` is INT.

I have tried to cast certain types like `INT` and `unsigned` but that does not work

EDIT: Table information:

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` date DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `article_fulltext` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_text` text NOT NULL,
  `html` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `article_ID` (`article_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `article_fulltext_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`article_ID`) REFERENCES `article` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Comment: It would make your question a lot easier to understand if you included the table definitions of `article` and `article_fulltext`

Comment: @AndyPreston do you mean results from `SHOW CREATE TABLE article_fulltext` ?

Comment: not sure this can be a reason but I think UDASSA must be single-quoted as string

Comment: Tried that, doesn't fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CAST()` is malformed and `INT` is not a valid type for [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), it should be `UNSIGNED`. This would still not work, as the whole`foreign key` would be passed into your parameterized query as a string, hence your 1366 error. And, the `CAST()` is pointless as the `ID` is already an `INT`.

It would need to be restructured, something like:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO article_fulltext (article_ID, body_text, html) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM article WHERE title = %s), %s, %s)"
val = ( article.title.strip(), article.text.strip(), article.html.strip() )
```

Fortunately, there is a cleaner way to retrieve the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) with `cursor.lastrowid`:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO article (title, author, summary, source) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
val = (article.title.strip(), ", ".join(article.authors), summary.strip(), url.strip())

mycursor.execute(sql, val)
last_insert_id = cursor.lastrowid
```

You should not be storing the string of authors in the article table. This should be normalized with a separate `authors` table and a many-to-many table joining `authors` with their `articles`.

Comment: `cursor.lastrowid` is indeed very helpful. Also, I didn't think about placing authors in a separate table, makes sense. Many thanks to you